# expect in bash: quoting with special characters and output as VAR

Tags: bash, special-characters, expect

I have this bash scipt

```
#!/bin/bash

Login="bla 0, xy;Z"          ##the spaces and the ',' and ';' are important!

expect -c "
    spawn telnet *HOST* 
    expect "Done."
    send '$Login'
    expect "Done."
    send "command 0".      ## the ' 0' is important! Same prob as with the password
    ???                    ## what do I have to do to get the output in a VAR?
    expect "Done."
    "
```

The two questions are:

1. the $Login is not interpreted as text from bash, so it thinks with 0 a new command starts... and ',' as well as ';' seems to be a problem too. escaping with '' did not work!?
2. How do I get the output as a $VAR to use it later?

Is this possible at all in bash? or do I have to use tcl (which I have never ever used or read anything about before)?

Thanks for advices!
andy

Comment: You're **always** using TCL when you use expect, including in your example above. `expect -c '...anything...'` -- the `...anything...` is TCL code.

Comment: Anyhow -- instead of `send '$Login'` and requiring the string `Login` to be replaced by bash, make Login an _environment_ variable so your TCL code can refer to the environment; then you no longer have any need for double quotes or otherwise for bash to perform expansions on content that's later parsed as code by expect. Moreover, because the content is seen by the TCL interpreter as data instead of as code, your spaces, comma, semicolon, etc. aren't prone to being misinterpreted.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.shellcheck.net/  , https://www.javatpoint.com/quotes-in-bash and https://linuxhint.com/bash_escape_quotes/ . Note that variables inside single quotes won't get expanded.

Comment: you can try my [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect/)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the useful comments above, single quotes have no special meaning in Tcl/expect, they are just ordinary characters that are being sent with the password.

As Charles writes, passing data via the environment is helpful.

Also, Tcl comments are a bit annoying: the `#` is only recognized as a comment if it occurs where a command starts, so you'll see me use `;#` below.

I find using a quoted heredoc removes quoting difficulties.

When you say "result in a VAR", I assume you want a *shell* variable?

untested

```sh
export Login="bla 0, xy;Z"
export HOST=something

VAR=$(expect << 'END_EXPECT'
    log_user 0              ;# turn off normal stdout of the interaction
                             # so we can capture only the output you want
    spawn telnet $env(HOST)
    expect "Done."
    send "$env(Login)\r"    ;# don't forget to "hit enter"
    expect "Done."
    send "command 0\r"

    # what do I have to do to get the output in a VAR?
    # use a regex capturing the command's output. Note that the command
    # itself appears in the output
    expect -re "command 0\r\n(.+)Done."

    # the shell will capture this output
    puts $expect_out(1,string)

    send "exit\r"        ;# or whatever you need to do to quit
    expect eof
END_EXPECT
)
```

Comment: Hey Glenn, thank you very much... this is very close but something is wrong with expect -re, I guess. I receive:

can't read "expect_re(1,string)": no such variable
    while executing
"puts $expect_re(1,string)"
Can you give me a hint what to do?

Comment: My bad, change `expect_re` to `expect_out`. I'll fix my answer

Comment: okay, no prob... but this raises another question: what is "wrong" with this VAR? Something is different....!? IF is not working the way it should for example:

`if [[ "${getPartitionNum}" = "0" ]]
        then activePartition=A
    elif [[ "${getPartitionNum}" = "1" ]]
        then activePartition=B
        else echo "there was a problem detecting active partition. please check."; exit 1
    fi`

even if the the output of getPartitionNum is 0 it always ends with "there was a problem detecting active partition. please check." And I don't know why

Comment: I suspect there are some "hidden" characters in there, probably `\r` and/or `\n`. In bash do `declare -p getPartitionNum` to inspect the value of the variable.